# Changing geoserver admin password

Tags: geoserver, security

How can I change the default password of geoserver admin from `geoserver` to something else?

I have tried two different things, but none worked. First thing I tried following the online documentation is to go to the data_dir at:

```
 /usr/local/lib/geoserver-2.5/data_dir/security
```

and I could only find

```
  <user enabled="true" name="admin" password="digest1:XXXX...">
```

in `usergroup/default/users.xml`. But I can't edit a digest.

The second thing I tried is to change the password from the web admin interface in the "Passwords" menu on the left panel. Although I can change the password, but it seems to be changing something called the master password. The password for `admin` remains the same.

I am using geoserver2.5 from osgeolive8.

Comment: Are you running it off the CD?

Comment: @BradHards I was running the live VM.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change the password via the web interface by going to the **Users,Groups, and Roles** link:

[image]

Once there, go to the **Users/Groups** tab and select the user which you want to edit

[image]

You can then change the passwords or any other details you need to change.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to change it using the password tab and it was not working, this is still the right way in 2.19, thanks

Comment: yes it is still the correct way to do it https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/ugr.html#security-webadmin-ugr

Comment: Still correct as of 2.23.2. @IanTurton may I suggest the 'Getting started' pages need updating as they are currently unclear. See: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/web-admin-quickstart/index.html#logging-in After Step 2, the guide should direct the user to change the admin password in the 'Users, Groups, Roles' page. Instead, the obvious (but incorrect) choice would be to go to the 'Passwords' page, which has a 'Change password' link (which doesn't seem to actually change the 'admin' password).

Comment: Please click on https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/main/doc/en/user/source/gettingstarted/web-admin-quickstart/index.rst and edit yourself - all the geoserver documentation is editable so people can keep it upto date

Comment: @IanTurton thanks, will look into that.