# GeoServer 2.7.4 admin/geoserver password remains the same

Tags: geoserver, security

This solution presented here: [How do I change geoserver admin password?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122621/how-do-i-change-geoserver-admin-password) doesn't work.

I have GeoServer 2.7.4 up and running, I went into the admin pane/ users, changed the default password, still no joy. Restarted the server, the old password still works. Interesting enough, the new password works too.

I went restarting the whole machine, with no luck. Then I deleted the admin user after creating a replacement one (admin2 with a different password), so now the "admin" account is gone, still I can use it to login. I know this is not the master root account, but why I can't get rid of it? I think all the other GeoServer instances of the same version have the same vulnerability.

Any ideas?

Comment: I repeated the same procedure on a 2.9.x (GeoServer 2.8.x and 2.7.x are no more supported) and I cannot reproduce the problem. What OS are you using? Is the file system writable by the user running GeoServer?

Comment: I use ubuntu 14.04 , and the install was done using the "ppa:geonode/stable" repository, which makes me think 2.7.4 is the latest stable build. Write permissions are OK, i can see it writing in /usr/share/geoserver/data/workspaces

Comment: The latest stable builds are 2.10.0 and 2.9.2, the 2.8 and 2.7 series are dead (2.7 has been out of support for more than six months)