# Sign In problem in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

While logging into GeoServer the `username` and `password` are not taken the ones which I had given during installation. Any suggestions?

[image: Problem_Log_in]

Comment: [@riya](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127691/riya), can you try then `User name: admin` and `Password: geoserver`. Does it work?

Comment: [@riya](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127691/riya), have you checked this article [How do I change geoserver admin password?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122621/how-do-i-change-geoserver-admin-password) already?

Comment: The login page does not look normal. It should like in the first image in this manual page http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/index.html#web-admin. I guess something went wrong with the installation.